# Converting LVM VolumeGroup/Volume identifiers to device names and vice versa

Tags: linux, lvm

### Question(s):

- What is the best way to convert LVM VolumeGroup/Volume identifiers (e.g. `system/var`) to device names (e.g. `/dev/mapper/system-var` or `/dev/system/var`) and vice versa?
- Is it safe to just use `/dev/VolumeGroup/Volume` or are there any caveats (as in the `/dev/mapper/VolumeGroup-Volume` form, where dashes are treated specially)?
- What are the essential differences in using `/dev/mapper/VolumeGroup-Volume` and `/dev/VolumeGroup/Volume`? Pro/Con for each form?

### Background:

I want to automatically create LVM snapshots for backup purposes.
The configuration should only include the source path in the filesystem (for this example `/var`).
Parsing `/etc/mtab` yields the device, which is mounted on that path:

```
# grep /var /etc/mtab
/dev/mapper/system-var /var ext4 rw 0 0
```

Now I can use `lvs` to find out VolumeGroup and Volume:

```
# lvs --noheadings /dev/mapper/system-var
var  system -wi-ao 18,62g
```

Create the snapshot:

```
# lvcreate -s -n var-snapshot -p r -l10%ORIGIN system/var
```

Now I need the device name to mount the snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answers to questions:

1. Prepend `/dev/`
2. It's safe
3. `/dev/mapper/$vg-$lv` is handled by dm udev rules, `/dev/$vg/$lv/` is handled by lvm udev rules.

## My previous answer, how to find out the answers:

I'm looking at an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system.

udev handles device node creation.

`/dev/mapper/` and `/dev/$vg/` only contain symlinks.

`grep lvm /lib/udev/rules.d/*` matches several files.

`60-persistent-storage-lvm.rules` contains this line:

```
ENV{DM_VG_NAME}=="?*", ENV{DM_LV_NAME}=="?*", ENV{DM_LV_LAYER}=="", SYMLINK+="$env{DM_VG_NAME}/$env{DM_LV_NAME}"
```

which seems to suggest that the `/dev/$vg/$lv` links will be created

Most of the files also point to `/usr/share/doc/lvm2/README.udev` which states that udev and lvm2 will create devices for LVs in `/dev/$vg/`.

The symlinks in `/dev/mapper/` seem to be the doing of `55-dm.rules`. Device Mapper can be used without Logical Volume Manager for e.g. encryption with LUKS.